# Website Triggering Page Download (Memory Saver?)

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome

I'm seeing a peculiar issue with my React web app. When the app has been open for a while, then i go back to the tab, the browser attempts to download and save the webpage (opening the system download prompt). This seems to be related to the tab going into Memory Saver mode in Chrome, however difficult to confirm this as the root cause.

The web app functions normally during regular use. Has anyone else seen this issue, or have an idea how to fix?